Jetpack Compose Navigation - Adding custom NavType results in immediate return to startDestination
I'm having a strange issue using Jetpack Navigation for Compose when using a custom NavType. Library is updated to 2.8.4, my code is based off of this tutorial:
https://medium.com/mercadona-tech/type-safety-in-navigation-compose-23c03e3d74a5
I have 3 screens:
@Serializable
object Home

@Serializable
object ChildA

@Serializable
data class ChildB(val customClass: CustomClass)

@Composable
fun TypeSafetyNavigation(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    val navController = rememberNavController()

    NavHost(navController, startDestination = HomeScreen) {
        composable<Home> {
            HomeScreen(
                modifier = modifier,
                onNavChildAClick = { navController.navigate(ChildA) },
                onNavChildBClick = { navController.navigate(ChildB) },
            )
        }

        composable<ChildA> {
            ChildAScreen(
                modifier = modifier,
            )
        }

        composable<ChildB>(
                    typeMap = mapOf(typeOf<CustomClass>() to serializableType<CustomClass>())
                ) { backStackEntry ->
            val bookDetail = backStackEntry.toRoute<ChildB>()

            ChildBScreen(
                modifier = modifier,
                customClass = customClass,
            )
        }
    }
}

inline fun <reified T : Any> serializableType(
    isNullableAllowed: Boolean = false,
    json: Json = Json,
) = object : NavType<T>(isNullableAllowed = isNullableAllowed) {
    override fun get(bundle: Bundle, key: String) =
        bundle.getString(key)?.let<String, T>(json::decodeFromString)

    override fun parseValue(value: String): T = json.decodeFromString(value)

    override fun serializeAsValue(value: T): String = json.encodeToString(value)

    override fun put(bundle: Bundle, key: String, value: T) {
        bundle.putString(key, json.encodeToString(value))
    }
}

Everything works when I navigate to ChildB, but when I try to navigate to ChildA, it immediately returns to Home, verified by adding a navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener with log statements. I've set break points in the NavController class and both navigateUp() and popBackStack() are not being called.
What is happening here?

Can you include the full code you are using for your serializableType?

@ianhanniballake edited to include code as requested

Does it start working if you override equals in your type?

The navigation with the custom NavType works perfectly, it's actually when I navigate to ChildA, it bounces right back to the start destination. If I remove the ChildB composable from the graph then navigation to ChildA works as expected

I don't think if you actually answered my question. Does implementing equals in your custom NavType make navigating to ChildA work?

@ianhanniballake took a bit to figure out exactly how but came up with the below code and it now works. Would love to know why.

Overriding equals as below solved the issue
inline fun <reified T : Any> serializableType(
    isNullableAllowed: Boolean = false,
    json: Json = Json,
) = object : CustomNavType<T>(
    type = T::class,
    isNullableAllowed = isNullableAllowed,
) {
    override fun get(bundle: Bundle, key: String) =
        bundle.getString(key)?.let<String, T>(json::decodeFromString)

    override fun parseValue(value: String): T = json.decodeFromString(value)

    override fun serializeAsValue(value: T): String = json.encodeToString(value)

    override fun put(bundle: Bundle, key: String, value: T) {
        bundle.putString(key, json.encodeToString(value))
    }

    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        if (this === other) return true
        if (other == null || javaClass != other.javaClass) return false
        val that = other as CustomNavType<*>
        return type == that.type
    }
}

abstract class CustomNavType<T : Any>(
    val type: KClass<T>,
    isNullableAllowed: Boolean = false,
) : NavType<T>(isNullableAllowed)

